# How to manipulate a 2 levels array of objects and transform it in another structure in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following array of objects that comes from a MySql query:

```
[
  {col1:1, col2:a},
  {col1:1, col2:b},
  {col1:1, col2:c},
  {col1:2, col2:d},
  {col1:2, col2:e},
  {col1:2, col2:f},
  {col1:3, col2:g},
  {col1:3, col2:h}
]
```

I would like to transform into the following object:

```
[
  {col1:1, col2:[a,b,c]},
  {col1:2, col2:[d,e,f]},
  {col1:3, col2:[e,g,h]}
]
```

Is there a way to perform this task using map or array filter?

Comment: This is a duplicate, as flagged above, but you could simply query your database to return the grouped result `SELECT col1, JSON_ARRAYAGG(col2) as col2 FROM table GROUP BY col1;`

Comment: Demo of above [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uR3yMHDXMCqdT5zwt3qzTb/0)

Comment: @pilchard that is better than manipulate in JS. It solved the issue. Tks